# Data missing in HTML on SSDT16 and Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I'm having an issue with the soft render of a simple report in both SSDT and Report Builder environments in 2016. I'm sure there is a sample solution but I'm unable to find a solution on the web/forum.

I'm actually just using a simple tablix from AdventureworksDW2016CTP3 with a couple of fields inserted. The data might initially display but disappears after modifying the field length or switching between design and preview. More interestingly, the report views perfectly when utilising print preview and it exports to .pdf correctly... and also views correctly when deployed to the report server.

All is installed locally on my laptop with Windows 10 and Administrator privileges. I have repaired and upgraded Visual Studio and SSDT to the latest version but without any luck.

I've added images of the simple design, soft render and print preview as well as Visual Studio System Info at the bottom.

Thanks

*Visual Studio Info*

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated) Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586
- SQL Server Analysis Services   13.0.1701.8
- Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer Version 13.0.1701.8
- SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61021.0
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

*SQL Server Integration Services*

- Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 13.0.1601.5
- SQL Server Reporting Services 13.0.1701.8
- Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 13.0.1701.8

*Images*

- [Design Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4lx6.png)
- [Soft Render / HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT239.png)
- [Print Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PanYn.png)

Comment: did you try re-create DataSet and Tablix ?

Comment: Long shot and might sound silly but have you tried hitting refresh on the report control. VS will use the cached rdl.data file until either a parameter value is changed or  you hit refresh.

Comment: Hi Canedean_AS / Chanom First,

I have already tried both of your solutions without any luck. I have also created a function to remove the data file. I have found other users stating that VS 2015 can be extremely buggy, but I'm wondering if this is actually due to SSDT 2015, rather than VS 2015. I have just reinstalled both VS 2015 and SSDT 2015 without any luck.

I have a feeling it might be a registry setting, and as it's a relative new laptop I might just rebuild as I really can't see a way around this at present - except with VS 2013 which works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing it appears that the problem came down to my graphics driver - Intel HD Graphics 5500.

The problem still occurred after I updated the driver so I then disabled it... which solved the problem. I then reinstalled the driver and all is now working as expected.

This link gave me the initial indication of the issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2894215/you-experience-performance-issues,-product-crashes,-or-rendering-issues-in-visual-studio-2015-and-visual-studio-2013